# Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes' after Storybook gets installed

Tags: javascript, typescript, npm, storybook

When I execute

```
npx storybook@latest init
```

to set up Storybook  (as result it modifies package.json)
then I'm unable to npm run the project because of:

```
Error: node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3139:14 - error TS2300: Duplicate identifier 'LibraryManagedAttributes'.

3139         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends
                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

  node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts:3308:14
    3308         type LibraryManagedAttributes<C, P> = C extends
                      ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    'LibraryManagedAttributes' was also declared here.
```

[image]

Tried several ways with no luck.
The new lines in package.json after executing `npx storybook@latest init`
are some new devDependencies:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@storybook/addon-essentials": "^7.6.3",
    "@storybook/addon-interactions": "^7.6.3",
    "@storybook/addon-links": "^7.6.3",
    "@storybook/angular": "^7.6.3",
    "@storybook/blocks": "^7.6.3",
    "@storybook/test": "^7.6.3",

    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",

    "storybook": "^7.6.3",
}
```

Is this a Storybook issue or Typescript  and how to resolve it?

I tried to add

```
"overrides": {
  "react": "^18.2.0"
}
```

as suggested after removing all node_modules - no luck.
P.S. No Yarn.

Any suggestions how to fix this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> node_modules/@types/react-dom/node_modules/@types/react/index.d.ts:3139:14

> node_modules/@types/react/ts5.0/index.d.ts:3308:14

This isn't about multiple versions of React, but multiple versions (and instances) of `@types/react`.

Make `@types/react` and `@types/react-dom` devDependencies if they aren't already; if you were using `yarn`, I'd tell you to `yarn why @types/react`.